# How to close/destroy chrome devtools ExtensionPanel programmatically?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have recently created a extension for devtools, which adds a new [ExtensionPanel](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels.html#type-ExtensionPanel) on devtools. Since this panel is useful only on certain pages, I wanted to show it conditionally depending on contents of current page. I can create a panel dynamically,depending on context of the page, but I was unable to find any way to close it (I've tried `window.close()` and panel itself doesn't have any methods like this).

So my question: Is there any way to close [ExtensionPanel](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels.html#type-ExtensionPanel) programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by DevTools at the moment -- if you add a panel or sidebar, it's for the life of DevTools front-end. All stock DevTools panels are displayed unconditionally and the rationale for the lack of API methods to remove panels is to avoid confusion created by panels coming and going. If a panel is not applicable to the page being inspected at the moment, you can perhaps display a banner explaining why it's not applicable.

Comment: Well, the problem is that at least I could have provided an option for users to close the panel automatically when it is not needed. If you have multiple devtools extensions and small screen this can be quite helpful

Comment: This would also be useful for development (HMR, etc).